# How to join an existing VM to VPN on Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, vpn, azure-vpn

I have couple of running services on Azure, that I want to connect.

For that I created a virtual network but I can't find a way to connect them, it seems like the only way to connect VMs to a private network is in the allocation phase.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit tricky

first of all you have to delete the VM from the VMs tab in the portal.

Why? (It will remove the VM but not the VHD Disks).

delete the cloud service, so u can use the same name again

create a new VM and choose from my disks the disk of the machine which u deleted

name it and you will be done

Comment: Felix is correct. You need to reprovision the VM's and cloud services and add them to the virtual network.

Comment: Man that is bad... It means a way too long downtime.

Comment: there is no other way, i know to do that... if the downtime is to long for you then clone your whole instance, do the configs i mentioned and delete the clone

Comment: @FelixLahmer not yet I need to schedule a downtime for it.